# How to throttle pipe in bash/shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, io

## Background

I am restoring a tar snapshot of a database.

While it is being restored, my computer is nearly unusable because of saturated disk I/O.

Unfortunately, my OS (Ubuntu 18.04) uses the deadline I/O scheduler, which ignores any concept of I/O priority.

## Question

Instead, I am trying to create a shell pipeline that throttles reading the source tar.

```
something db.tar.gz | tar xzf -
```

I thereby could control my write speed and fake my OS's lack of a real I/O scheduler.

How can I do this?

## Attempt

So far, I have tried `pv`, however it seems unsuitable for this task.

```
pv -L 5M db.tar.gz | tar xzf -
```

The progress meter regularly shows speeds multiple times higher than the limit, and my computer locks up when this happens.

Answer (score 0):

It's not normal for a system to choke on disk IO and require restricting throughput, but you asked on StackOverflow and not ServerFault, so...

The `pv` command works as advertised. The reason why you see the speed spike is that `tar` was temporarily too slow, so `pv` let it read faster to catch back up to an average of 5 MiB/s.

Any given chunk of 5MB gzipped data could correspond to anything from 5MB to 100MB+ of uncompressed data, so to make processing more uniform, you can apply it *after* decompression instead:

```
gzip -d < db.tar.gz | pv -L 5M | tar x
```

Failing that, you can hack together a bash loop that will write at a steady pace and not allow catch-ups:

```
cat db.tar.gz |
    while sleep 1 && [[ $(LC_ALL=C dd bs=5M count=1 2>&1 >&3) != "0+0 records"* ]] 3>&1; do true; done |
    pv |
    tar xz
```

Comment: I should say, programs that write to disk a lot (I've noticed Chrome is a big offender) are blocked. If a program doesn't write to disk, it's fine.